# Google Cloud Console: Deleting Files From Console

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have just started using Google Cloud Storage services. 
I have manage to upload a file but I can't see from the developer console how to delete it since the Delete button is not active.
I am using the default bucket

[image]

Comment: Do you have admin rights to this project?

Comment: The file may have an ACL that doesn't give your web console user permissions to delete it. Do you see a menu icon (3 vertically stacked dots) to the far right of your **file**?  That should have an option to *Edit permissions* which should show you the current permissions.  You can use [`gsutil`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) to fix the permissions using a project admin's account.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the ACL also check it with different browser.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was going for a **free trial version**. I could not use any of the buttons with the default version (no billing set). As soon as I entered my credit card details the buttons came back to life.

If you decide not to do the free trial or the issue persists after signing up, you might find these commands useful:

gsutil acl ch -u "your-email":O gs://your-app-name.appspot.com

gsutil acl ch -g "google-cloud-storage-id":O gs://your-app-name.appspot.com

You can find the Google Cloud Storage ID in Developers Console -> Storage -> Cloud Storage -> Storage Settings under Project Access tab.

Consult the documentation for more info https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl